# Using javascript to check if list item contains one text or the other, then assign static text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ecommerce website that shows product price in the following format:

- **$36.99** (for items with regular pricing)
- (crossed out $36.99) **$32.99** - for products that have a sale price.

I'm trying to use javascript to check if the product has a regular price or a sale price and assign the text "From" in front of the price. For example:

- **From $36.99**
- **$36.99 From $32.99**

The 36.99 in 2nd example would be striked through. I realize this requires an IF statement to check which type of price exists. This is what I have so far but suspect my syntax is wrong:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#CategoryContent .ProductList  li").each(function() {

        var salePrice = $(".SalePrice", this).text();           
        var price = $(".p-price", this).text();

        if $(".SalePrice", this).text("From " + salePrice); {
            else {$(".p-price", this).text("From " + price);}
        }


}); });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x18qp9jj/

Comment: It would be helpful in this case if we could see the html that your javascript is parsing. Could you put something into codepen.io or jsfiddle.net?

Comment: yes, please, always try to put a full fiddle

Comment: Sorry about that! Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x18qp9jj/

Comment: Where is the `SalePrice` class in the DOM? What are you even trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is very strange and syntactically wrong.

It should look like:

```
if ( A COMPARISON STATEMENT ) {
    $(".SalePrice", this).text("From " + salePrice)
} else {
    $(".p-price", this).text("From " + price);
}
```

But I am not sure what you really meant to compare.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong. To make a conditional statement (if) in javascript , you have to use the following syntax :

```
if (condition) {
   statement1;
   ...
} else | else if (condition) {
   statement2;
   ...
}
```

The else | else if expression is optional.

Where condition is an expression that evaluates to a [Boolean object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean).
So, your code will end something like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#CategoryContent .ProductList  li").each(function() {

      var salePrice = $(".SalePrice", this).text();
      var price = $(".p-price", this).text();

    if (salePrice != "") {
        $(".SalePrice", this).text("From " + salePrice);
      } else {
        $(".p-price", this).text("From " + price);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CategoryContent">
  <ul class="ProductList ">
    <li><em class="p-price">$36.99</em>
    </li>
    <li><span class=".SalePrice">$37.99 </span><em class="p-price">$33.99</em>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For further reference, check about [if expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: This is close to what I need. How do I format the condition to check if the class is p-price or SalePrice? I basically need to add the word "From" to before one or the other class, but not both.

Comment: I updated my answer with the information of your comment. Hope this will help you.